# Match multiple values in array

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have the following data structure:

```
[{"url":"http://guyanachronicle.com/","originalUrl":"http://www.guyanachronicle.com","applications":[]}
    ,{"url":"http://www.lightbot.com","originalUrl":"http://www.lightbot.com","applications":[{"name":"Apache","confidence":"100","version":"","icon":"Apache.svg","website":"http://apache.org","categories":["Web Servers"]},{"name":"Facebook","confidence":"100","version":"","icon":"Facebook.svg","website":"http://facebook.com","categories":["Widgets"]},{"name":"Google Analytics","confidence":"100","version":"","icon":"Google Analytics.svg","website":"http://google.com/analytics","categories":["Analytics"]},{"name":"Twitter","confidence":"100","version":"","icon":"Twitter.svg","website":"http://twitter.com","categories":["Widgets"]},{"name":"jQuery","confidence":"100","version":"1.4","icon":"jQuery.svg","website":"http://jquery.com","categories":["JavaScript Frameworks"]}]}
    ,{"url":"http://www.fitnessfirst.com.au","originalUrl":"http://www.fitnessfirst.com.au","applications":[{"name":"AdInfinity","confidence":"100","version":"","icon":"AdInfinity.png","website":"http://adinfinity.com.au","categories":["Advertising Networks"]},{"name":"CloudFlare","confidence":"100","version":"","icon":"CloudFlare.svg","website":"http://www.cloudflare.com","categories":["CDN"]},{"name":"Facebook","confidence":"100","version":"","icon":"Facebook.svg","website":"http://facebook.com","categories":["Widgets"]},{"name":"Google Analytics","confidence":"100","version":"UA","icon":"Google Analytics.svg","website":"http://google.com/analytics","categories":["Analytics"]},{"name":"Google Tag Manager","confidence":"100","version":"","icon":"Google Tag Manager.png","website":"http://www.google.com/tagmanager","categories":["Tag Managers"]},{"name":"Microsoft ASP.NET","confidence":"100","version":"4.0.30319","icon":"Microsoft ASP.NET.png","website":"http://www.asp.net","categories":["Web Frameworks"]},{"name":"Modernizr","confidence":"100","version":"","icon":"Modernizr.png","website":"http://www.modernizr.com","categories":["JavaScript Frameworks"]},{"name":"New Relic","confidence":"100","version":"","icon":"New Relic.png","website":"http://newrelic.com","categories":["Analytics"]},{"name":"Nginx","confidence":"100","version":"","icon":"Nginx.svg","website":"http://nginx.org/en","categories":["Web Servers"]},{"name":"OWL Carousel","confidence":"100","version":"","icon":"OWL Carousel.png","website":"https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/","categories":["Widgets"]},{"name":"Optimizely","confidence":"100","version":"","icon":"Optimizely.png","website":"http://optimizely.com","categories":["Analytics"]},{"name":"YouTube","confidence":"100","version":"","icon":"YouTube.png","website":"http://www.youtube.com","categories":["Video Players"]},{"name":"jQuery","confidence":"100","version":"1.11.1","icon":"jQuery.svg","website":"http://jquery.com","categories":["JavaScript Frameworks"]},{"name":"IIS","confidence":"100","version":"","icon":"IIS.png","website":"http://www.iis.net","categories":["Web Servers"]},{"name":"Windows Server","confidence":"100","version":"","icon":"Microsoft.svg","website":"http://microsoft.com/windowsserver","categories":["Operating Systems"]}]}
    ,{"url":"https://www.totaltools.com.au/","originalUrl":"http://www.totaltools.com.au","applications":[{"name":"Facebook","confidence":"100","version":"","icon":"Facebook.svg","website":"http://facebook.com","categories":["Widgets"]},{"name":"Google Analytics","confidence":"100","version":"UA","icon":"Google Analytics.svg","website":"http://google.com/analytics","categories":["Analytics"]},{"name":"Google Tag Manager","confidence":"100","version":"","icon":"Google Tag Manager.png","website":"http://www.google.com/tagmanager","categories":["Tag Managers"]},{"name":"Hotjar","confidence":"100","version":"","icon":"Hotjar.png","website":"https://www.hotjar.com","categories":["Analytics"]},{"name":"Magento","confidence":"100","version":"2","icon":"Magento.png","website":"http://www.magentocommerce.com","categories":["Ecommerce"]},{"name":"Prototype","confidence":"100","version":"","icon":"Prototype.png","website":"http://www.prototypejs.org","categories":["JavaScript Frameworks"]},{"name":"RequireJS","confidence":"100","version":"","icon":"RequireJS.png","website":"http://requirejs.org","categories":["JavaScript Frameworks"]},{"name":"Twitter Bootstrap","confidence":"100","version":"","icon":"Twitter Bootstrap.png","website":"http://getbootstrap.com","categories":["Web Frameworks"]},{"name":"Underscore.js","confidence":"100","version":"","icon":"Underscore.js.png","website":"http://underscorejs.org","categories":["JavaScript Frameworks"]},{"name":"jQuery","confidence":"100","version":"","icon":"jQuery.svg","website":"http://jquery.com","categories":["JavaScript Frameworks"]},{"name":"jQuery Mobile","confidence":"100","version":"","icon":"jQuery Mobile.svg","website":"http://jquerymobile.com","categories":["Mobile Frameworks"]},{"name":"jQuery UI","confidence":"100","version":"","icon":"jQuery UI.svg","website":"http://jqueryui.com","categories":["JavaScript Frameworks"]},{"name":"PHP","confidence":"100","version":"","icon":"PHP.svg","website":"http://php.net","categories":["Programming Languages"]}]}
    ,{"url":"http://www.bestandless.com.au","originalUrl":"http://www.bestandless.com.au","applications":[]}
    ,{"url":"http://www.flightsimstore.com","originalUrl":"http://www.flightsimstore.com","applications":[{"name":"Google Analytics","confidence":"100","version":"","icon":"Google Analytics.svg","website":"http://google.com/analytics","categories":["Analytics"]},{"name":"HeadJS","confidence":"50","version":"","icon":"HeadJS.png","website":"http://headjs.com","categories":["JavaScript Frameworks"]},{"name":"Nginx","confidence":"100","version":"1.12.0","icon":"Nginx.svg","website":"http://nginx.org/en","categories":["Web Servers"]},{"name":"PHP","confidence":"100","version":"5.3.29","icon":"PHP.svg","website":"http://php.net","categories":["Programming Languages"]},{"name":"SWFObject","confidence":"100","version":"","icon":"SWFObject.png","website":"http://github.com/swfobject/swfobject","categories":["Miscellaneous"]},{"name":"StatCounter","confidence":"100","version":"","icon":"StatCounter.png","website":"http://www.statcounter.com","categories":["Analytics"]},{"name":"SumoMe","confidence":"100","version":"","icon":"SumoMe.png","website":"http://sumome.com","categories":["Widgets","Marketing Automation"]},{"name":"osCommerce","confidence":"100","version":"","icon":"osCommerce.png","website":"http://www.oscommerce.com","categories":["Ecommerce"]},{"name":"MySQL","confidence":"100","version":"","icon":"MySQL.svg","website":"http://mysql.com","categories":["Databases"]}]}]);
```

That I uploaded to a collection in MongoDB called websites (it essentially is just a list of URLs and the applications that are running on them)

I use the following query to return all websites who have a certain application installed:

```
db.websites.find({"applications.name":"osCommerce"}).pretty();
```

This works and returns a list of websites using "osCommerce" however, when trying to use $and to search for websites that are using multiple applications my query doesn't work.

I'm trying to use:

```
db.inventory.find( { $and: [ {applications.name:{"Apache"}}, 
{applications.name: {"osCommerce"}} ] } ).pretty();
```

With no luck, what is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want [`$all`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/all/)

```
db.inventory.find({
  "applications.name": { "$all": [ "Apache", "osCommerce" ] }
})
```

Or combined with with [`$elemMatch`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) if you want more conditions than just `"name"` inside the array:

```
db.inventory.find({
  "applications": { 
    "$all": ]
      { "$elemMatch": { "name": "Apache" } },
      { "$elemMatch": { "name": "osCommerce" } }
    ]
  }
})
```

Noting though that the data you present in the question has no document that matches this condition.

If you want "either" value then that is an [`$in`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/) query:

```
db.inventory.find({ 
  "applications.name": { "$in": [ "Apache", "osCommerce" ] }
})
```

or in fact represented with [`$or`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/or/) if you wanted "multiple properties" just like above:

```
db.inventory.find({
  "$or": [
    { "applications": { "$elemMatch": { "name": "Apache" } } }
    { "applications": { "$elemMatch": { "name": "osCommerce" } } }
  ]
})
```

Comment: Yep, there will be a lot more data than just this, thank you so much!